# Infinite loop inference Prolog

Tags: prolog, inference-engine, prolog-metainterpreter

An infinite loop is generated when the inferential motor is activated to make the necessary inferences.

The rules and facts have been defined according to a specific syntax for the meta-interpreter I am using.

The rule is a quintuple in which the second field is the consequence of the rule while the third field are the conditions for activating a rule.

The cycle is caused by the updating of the id (I1) through the term nextID, which I used to make sure that each assert the id is incremented This is my knowledge base:

Rules:

```
rule(1,[gn(Name,Surname,I1),retract(nextID(I)),nextID(I1)],
and([person(Name,Surname),nextID(I),call_p(I1 is I+1),Name=='john']),1,1).
```

Facts:

```
fact(1,nextID(0),1).
fact(2,person(john,black),1).
```

How should I modify the rule in such a way that the infinite loop is not created?

Comment: no it's not syntax error

Comment: `nextID (0)` is invalid syntax. It should be `nextID(0)`. It's the same with all other compound terms (except for `Name == 'john'`).

Comment: You can't have a space between the functor and the left parenthesis when writing a compound term in Prolog. So, for example, you want, `fact(1, nextID(0), 1).` not `fact (1, nextID (0), 1).` But since you've evidently run this code and encountered a loop, I suppose how you've entered it here isn't how it is in reality.

Comment: the spaces are derived from the copy and paste but I assure you that in the code there are not.

Comment: and then the spaces would have returned syntax error while in my case the syntax is correct but the problem is in execution

Comment: the spaces were generated for entering the question on google translate. `call_p` is a command of meta-interpreter that makes comparisons and assignments between numerical variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the rule fields, I would expect a different formulation for that rule:

```
rule(
    1,
    [retract(nextID(I)), call_p(I1 is I+1), assertz(nextID(I1), gn(Name,Surname,I1)], 
    and([person(Name,Surname), Name == 'john']),
    1,
    1
).
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
IF
    person(Name,Surname), Name == 'john'
THEN
    retract(nextID(I)), call_p(I1 is I+1),
    assertz(nextID(I1), gn(Name,Surname,I1)
```

But it's hard to tell exactly without knowing the details of your rule engine.

**Update**

Given the formulation of facts, notably `fact(1,nextID(0),1)`, I wouldn't expect, however, that the embedded calls to `retract/1` and `assertz/1` would work. Isn't `call_p/1` the escape mechanism to call Prolog goals from rules?

Comment: the effect of the execution is that it continually creates new nextIDs so the rule is always invoked. I would like the loop to stop after the `gn` assert and the `nextID` update

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case with the alternative rule formulation that I suggest in my answer?

Comment: the second field of the rule is used only for `assert` and `retract`, to perform the assert it is sufficient to insert the fact to assert without specifying the command `assert`, while for `retract` it is necessary to specify it. `call_p (I1 is I + 1)` is to be placed in the third field of the rule otherwise `call_p` is considered a compound term.

Comment: Is it possible to use `retractall` instead of `retract`?